# Thread.join's timeout does not work when thread is computing a sum

Tags: python, multithreading

In the following code:

```
import threading

def infinite_loop():
    while True:
        pass

def huge_sum():
    return sum(range(2**100))

thread = threading.Thread(target=huge_sum)
thread.start()
thread.join(1)

print("Done")
```

I expect the script to print "Done" after one second since `join()` will timeout, but instead the script hangs. If you replace the call to `huge_sum` with `infinite_loop`, it works fine. The problem seems to be with the built-in `sum()` function.

Is there a way I can reliably get something like `join()`'s timeout behavior *no matter what the thread is doing*? I don't mind wacky metaprogramming solutions, this is for a very niche application. However, for the most part I cannot modify the code being executed inside the thread (e.g. "use a loop instead of `sum`" is not a solution).

Linux, Python 3.8.

Comment: This is a pretty interesting question. I've found that `max` and `min` have the same result as using `sum` in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at `builtin_sum_impl` in [`bltinmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c), `int` and `float` are optimized to perform the sum without releasing the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). Python only allows byte code to execute in a single thread at a time. Every so often the byte code executor will release the GIL so that other threads can run.

C code can release the GIL, letting python level code run in parallel. But `sum` doesn't do that. It holds the GIL while summing `int` so that it doesn't have to worry about other threads changing the thing being summed while in progress. That also means that no python code gets to run in any thread until it completes.

One option is to do the work in a different process. For a forking operating system like linux, you could use a separate process to sum. The child can read parent memory so even if there is a large list in memory, it works. This adds the overhead of creating the child process, so not free.

Its even better if you can generate the data in the child processs, especially if you want to do multiple sums in parallel. In your `range` example, you would to just that.

Alternately, if you have a large set of integers to work with, you could move to numpy arrays where some operations like `array.sum` release the GIL. It wouldn't work in your example because `range(2**100)` is too big. But I assume that's just an example.

You could scale this to multiple processes running in parallel, perhaps using `multiprocessing.Pool`. The best way to do this depends on several factors. For instance, If you have a large set of data in the parent, you don't want to pass it as a parameter in `.map()` (or other pool methods) because python has to copy the parameters to the workers. Instead you'd use some global variable that the worker just happens to know about.

Comment: You know, I was taking a look at `bltinmodule.c` and I couldn't figure out where exactly the GIL gets activated and deactivated. Could you point me in the right direction? I thought it was something to do with `PyThreadState`, but no instance of that exists in `builtin_sum_impl`.

Comment: @BrockBrown - Good question. When in the non-optimized code, `sum` will need to call the object's `__add__` method and thats where byte code level stuff happens. I haven't dug that deep.

Answer (score 1):

[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

> The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency,
> effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock by using
> subprocesses instead of threads.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f():
    sum(range(2**100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f)
    p.start()
    p.join(1)
    print("Done")
```

Comment: But suppose you want to run 1,000 of those simultaneously with fully functional timeout. How would you implement this?

Comment: @Brock Brown It seems that this is not worth in the task.